# 'Session ID is null' error on IE in BrowserStack

Tags: automated-tests, internet-explorer-10, webdriver-io, browserstack

I'm running some tests on multiple browsers/devices on BrowserStack using WebdriverIO. While the tests execute fine on all other browsers, on IE10, it always fails with an error on BrowserStack saying

> 'Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()? Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
>   System info: host: 'x-xxx-xx-xxx', ip: 'x.xxx.xx.xxx', os.name:
>   'windows', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_151' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver'

The same tests run fine in parallel on other browsers, so it doesn't like a problem with quit() getting called prematurely.

Comment: Could you share the capabilities and minimal code snippet to reproduce the issue? I am using capabilities: 
[{
    os: 'Windows',
    os_version: '8',
    browser: 'IE',
    browser_version: '10'
  }] 
and it seems to work well on IE 10 on browserstack